# Inserting Rows into Access Table Using Excel Macro

Tags: vba, excel, ms-access

I have a macro that inserts data from Excel into an Access table. Each time it runs there may be 10k -250k rows to insert. I have experimented with using an empty database/table but it still takes 60s+ to run. Are there any ways to speed it up?

Thanks

```
Option Explicit

Sub CopyToAccess()

    Dim accessFile  As String
    Dim accessTable As String
    Dim sht         As Worksheet
    Dim lastRow     As Long
    Dim lastColumn  As Integer
    Dim con         As Object
    Dim rs          As Object
    Dim sql         As String
    Dim i           As Long
    Dim j           As Integer

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    accessFile = "xxxxxxxxxxxaccdb"

    If FileExists(accessFile) = False Then
        MsgBox "The Access file doesn't exist!", vbCritical, "Invalid Access file path"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    accessTable = "2022"
                
    On Error Resume Next
    Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Store")
    If Err.number <> 0 Then
        MsgBox "The given worksheet does not exist!", vbExclamation, "Invalid Sheet Name"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    Err.Clear
        
    With sht
        lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
        lastColumn = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    End With
    
    If lastRow < 2 Or lastColumn < 1 Then
        MsgBox "There are no data in the given worksheet!", vbCritical, "Empty Data"
        Exit Sub
    End If
        
    Set con = CreateObject("ADODB.connection")
    
    If Err.number <> 0 Then
        MsgBox "The connection was not created!", vbCritical, "Connection Error"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    Err.Clear
    
    con.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & accessFile
    
    sql = "SELECT * FROM " & accessTable
    
    Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
    
    If Err.number <> 0 Then
        Set rs = Nothing
        Set con = Nothing
        MsgBox "The recordset was not created!", vbCritical, "Recordset Error"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    Err.Clear
             
    rs.CursorType = 1   'adOpenKeyset on early binding
    rs.LockType = 3     'adLockOptimistic on early binding
        
    rs.Open sql, con

    For i = 2 To lastRow
        rs.AddNew
        For j = 1 To lastColumn
            'This is how it will look like the first time (i = 2, j = 1):
            'rs("FirstName") = "Bob"
            rs(sht.Cells(1, j).Value) = sht.Cells(i, j).Value
        Next j
        rs.Update
    Next i
        
    rs.Close
    con.Close
    
    Set rs = Nothing
    Set con = Nothing
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    
End Sub

Function FileExists(FilePath As String) As Boolean

 
    On Error Resume Next
    If Len(FilePath) > 0 Then
        If Not Dir(FilePath, vbDirectory) = vbNullString Then FileExists = True
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0
 
End Function
```

Comment: There is a similar discussion on SO: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26906778/excel-vbaselect-range-from-excel-and-insert-into-access-database